# Hi! How is doing?

Tags: american-english, greetings

Is it possible to greet someone asking "How is doing?" When I was in US, many times I heard a phrase "Hi! How is doing?" or maybe it was a misunderstanding and the phrase was "How are you doing?"

Comment: "How *you* doing?", pronounced almost "How ye doin?"

Comment: There also "What's doing?" on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=what's%20doing)

Comment: Whatever you heard, translated to writing, that is totally wrong. What area of the US did you hear this in? Anyway, you might be interested in committing to [ELL](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners).

Answer (score 5):

"How is doing?" is definitely **not** an acceptable greeting in any form of English with which I am familiar. Most likely you've heard an extremely reduced form of "How are you doing?" The levels of reduction go like this:

1. How are you doing?
2. How you doing?
3. How ya doin'? [hajə'duɪn]

It's also  possible that some people said "How's ya doing?", as the word *how's* (also sometimes spelled *howse*) is a variant of *how* in some dialects.

Comment: Maybe OP got his misunderstanding from *"How **is** it going?"* (usually contracted to *"How's it going?"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's another likely possibility that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Or maybe even [Hi! How's it doing?](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22hi+how%27s+it+doing%22&oq=%22hi+how%27s+it+doing%22&gs_l=hp.3...1912.7554.0.7792.26.23.3.0.0.1.207.2472.15j6j2.23.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.DRcPBI8t2gw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=e6a761ab7c11c94c&bpcl=38093640&biw=1142&bih=742) which is definitely non-standard English, but is occasionally heard. (But I think @FumbleFingers' suggestion of "going" is more likely.)

Comment: @Peter Shor: I don't think I've ever heard anyone say *"Hi! How's it doing?"* - so unless you have, I'm inclined to think those Google hits (only actually 46 when I page thru) are all non-native speakers. Some Internet hits obviously are, and the search term gets no hits at all in Google Books. On the other hand, I'm quite familiar with [Hi! How's it **hanging**?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hi+how's+it+hanging%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and even that occurs only once in GB.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: right; they all look like non-native speakers.

Comment: "How is it going?" -faster-> "How isit going?" -faster-> "How izit going?" -faster-> "How izz going?" -faster-> "How iz going?" -faster-> "How is going?" if you say it fast enough you can barely hear the "it"..  or the it is just omitted like the "are" in "How are you doing?" vs "How you doing?"